# Protools 9 mountain lion compatability

Tags: recommendations, computer, pro-tools-9, operation

Hi Jedi does protools 9 function properly on mountain lion 10.8.2 os? I wanna upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I have had serious problems with PT 9 and ML. PT 9 has constant buffering errors despite re-setting them, it crashes on a regular basis and freezes, comes back to life and then freezes again. Very frustrating. The only solution I found was to rn PT off of a Lacie drive which seemed to solve most of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only 9.0.6 works in ML.